# Perform Custom GLM using sklearn/Scikit-Learn

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I was looking to implement custom GLM using sklearn/Scikit-learn. The same is possible with statsmodel for example using statsmodel we could use below code

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
data = [(300,1),(200,0),(170,1),(420,1),(240,1),(133,0),(323,1),(150,0),(230,0),(499,0)]
Labels = ['datapoint','value']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=Labels)
glm_linear = sm.GLM(df.value, df.datapoint, family=sm.families.Gaussian(sm.families.links.identity()))
res = glm_linear.fit()
print(res.summary())
```

Here as we see we can pass any link and random function using family attribute in `sm.GLM` method.

I was looking for something similar in sklearn

Answer (score 1):

You can use sklearn [TweedieRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.TweedieRegressor.html) with parameter `power=0` to specify the normal distribution:

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import TweedieRegressor
import pandas as pd

data = [(300,1), (200,0), (170,1), (420,1), (240,1), (133,0), (323,1), (150,0), (230,0), (499,0)]
Labels = ['datapoint','value']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=Labels)
X, y = df.datapoint, df.value

glm_gaussian = TweedieRegressor(power=0, fit_intercept=False)
glm_gaussian.fit(X.to_numpy()[:, None], y)

print(glm_gaussian.coef_)
array([0.00173114])
```